# fluent nhibernate automap version column

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, fluent, automapping, optimistic

Current code in my convention:

```
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IVersionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column("RowVersion");
        instance.Not.Nullable();
        instance.UnsavedValue("0");
        instance.Default(1);
    }
```

This doesn't render the RowVersion as a version column. It treats RowVersion as just another column.

So my question is how do you add Row Version Concurrency using Fluent Nhibernate?

Answer (score 1):

The `VersionStep` class only looks for properties that match the names of `Version` or `Timestamp`.  Your property will have to match that name.  Replacing `VersionStep` to change the naming rules is another option.